Did Israel bombing the oil terminal in the port of Hodeidah have any strategic effect on the Houthis?
Are they suffering from an increased shortage of fuel or something, as a result of that strike (in July)?
(Some years ago, the Houthis and the UN were complaining that weapons inspections were causing tanker delays at Hodeidah, causing a humanitarian crisis. Thus far, I couldn't find anything similar reported following the 2024 Israeli air strike though. True, the UN might be less inclined to complain on Houthis' behalf this time, given that their own workers have been targeted by the Houthis recently.)

It's an interesting thing that at the same time the Israeli government insists that UN human rights workers are Hamas-loving terrorists, the Houthis insist that they are Israel-loving spies.

How did the tanker delays cause a humanitarian crisis? Was maybe oil income going directly to Houthis?

@Obie2.0 Well, they aren't the same UN workers, so... But I agree with the sentiment.

Also, interesting to see that the Houthis have maintained the rigorous respect for the integrity of international shipping that they had in 2015..

@NoDataDumpNoContribution the link says that it was an import terminal for gas product. I do not know if Yemen had oil reserves or not. But if they have no refineries they would need to import gasoline, even if they were literally floating in crude oil.

The UN is projecting famine in parts of Hodeda too, but says nothing about fuel here https://apnews.com/article/un-yemen-houthis-humanitarian-rights-arrests-famine-5924ba2d1320cbb4cb3adcbc5b3c4f57

As far as the Houthis attacking ships in the Red Sea  that have no connection to Israel, the Israeli strike on the Hodeidah port doesn't seem to have made any difference. As far as causing them to lose their interest in attacking Israel itself it seems to have been at least a temporary successful  deterrent. Particularly when you factor in that the Houthis attacks on Israel  before  Israel attacked the Hodeidah port were becoming increasingly aggressive
https://www.meforum.org/articles/israels-hodeidah-strike-briefly-deterred-houthis

Yeah, it seems to have bought Israel a couple of months without attack from the Houthis, although that ended recently.
